# How to identify static pods via kubectl command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have several pods in 2 nodes in my Kubernetes cluster. (Please see below).

Is there a way I can tell which ones are static pods? (maybe a `kubectl` command of sort?)

Thanks!

```
controlplane $ k get pods -A -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP            NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-h865q                1/1     Running   0          119s   10.244.0.5    node02   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-z4j6f                1/1     Running   0          119s   10.244.1.5    node01         <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-a1b2k7h7                      1/1     Running   0          2m9s   172.17.0.79   node02   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-g8j4k8o8            1/1     Running   0          2m9s   172.17.0.79   node02   <none>           <none>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Checking the owner reference of a static pod using `kubectl describe` command should indicate that such a pod is **not** controlled by a `ReplicaSet` but rather from `Node/controlplane`

Comment: Also: static pods always have a -${NODENAME} appended to their name, indicating which node controls this static pod.

Answer (score 16):

You can filter by the [`OwnerReference.Kind`](https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds). Static pods have the **`Node`** ownerReference kind.

You can use `--custom-columns` to list all your pods and its owner references. Example:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTROLLER:.metadata.ownerReferences[].kind,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace
NAME                                        CONTROLLER   NAMESPACE
busybox-6ff78776d5-k56fx                    ReplicaSet   default
nginx-6b87f7d77c-rq6fl                      ReplicaSet   default
coredns-74ff55c5b-xpgnq                     ReplicaSet   kube-system
etcd-minikube                               Node         kube-system
ingress-nginx-admission-create-n6j7k        Job          kube-system
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-45xvw         Job          kube-system
ingress-nginx-controller-65cf89dc4f-g7lwm   ReplicaSet   kube-system
kindnet-44pq8                               DaemonSet    kube-system
kindnet-nqhg9                               DaemonSet    kube-system
kube-apiserver-minikube                     Node         kube-system
kube-controller-manager-minikube            Node         kube-system
kube-proxy-nmzbn                            DaemonSet    kube-system
kube-proxy-wlmdz                            DaemonSet    kube-system
kube-scheduler-minikube                     Node         kube-system
metrics-server-58966dd6b9-schjr             ReplicaSet   kube-system
storage-provisioner                         <none>       kube-system
```

Or use [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to filter only the Static pods (`kind == "Node"`):

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '.items | map(select(.metadata.ownerReferences[]?.kind == "Node" ) | .metadata.name) | .[]'
etcd-minikube
kube-apiserver-minikube
kube-controller-manager-minikube
kube-scheduler-minikube
```

Comment: FYI - To add a column for the node name and grep for Node: `kubectl get pods -A -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTROLLER:.metadata.ownerReferences[].kind,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NODE:.spec.nodeName | grep Node`

Answer (score 2):

You can use that:

- For count static pod:

```
kubectl get pods -A --no-headers | awk '{print $2 " -n " $1 "\n"}' | xargs --max-lines=1 kubectl describe pods | grep "Controlled By:  Node/controlplane" | wc -l
```

- For list what is static pod:

```
kubectl get pods -A --no-headers | awk '{print $2 " -n " $1 "\n"}' | xargs --verbose --max-lines=1 kubectl describe pods | grep "Controlled By:  Node/controlplane"
```

Answer (score 1):

On Kubernetes v1.16.3 metadata.ownerReferences.kind isn't a thing so the recommended answer here didn't work.
I was able to identify Static Pods by looking at the metadata.labels.tier key/value pair with equal to "control-plane" with jq using the following.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '.items | map(select(.metadata.labels.tier == "control-plane" ) | .metadata.name) | .[]'
```

Comment: Static pods don't necessarily have a specific label, nor do they have to be on your master nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
ontrolplane ~ ➜  kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-mmm9q                  1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-ptks8                  1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system    coredns-5d78c9869d-p6tv6               1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system    coredns-5d78c9869d-q4s44               1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system    etcd-controlplane                      1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system    kube-apiserver-controlplane            1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-controlplane   1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system    kube-proxy-n8crp                       1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system    kube-proxy-s96g7                       1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system    kube-scheduler-controlplane            1/1     Running   0          41m
```

You just have to look for pods name which end with particular node name. Means owner of POD is node (control plane) in place of standard POD names. Are static pod

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the command below and check the pods with *-controlplane* appended in their name.

```bash
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all pods in all namespaces, and look for the ones that have an `ownerReferences` a node:

```bash
kubectl get pods -A -ojson | jq -r '.items | map(select(.metadata.ownerReferences[0].kind == "Node" ) | .metadata.name) | .[]'
```

Also Static pods have the node name in their name:

[image: node]

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers provide either lengthy terminal commands or very short description of what the commands actually do.

The shortest possible command to identify a static pod via `kubectl`:

`kubectl describe pods -A | grep -i Controlled`

will list all pods in all namespaces and check for the controlled by field. The `Node/***` presence on stdout indicates static pods presence.

Note: this assumes of course that a cluster already exists. If you are bootstrapping your own cluster, or you are curious about how `kubeadm` works, you can inspect the `kubelet` node - e.g. by `ssh` into it - and search the local directory for `pod manifests` files (usually at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` and/or `/var/lib/kubelet`)